# How do I stop automatically unmuting when playing a Youtube Video?

Tags: 11.10, sound, youtube, mute

Ubuntu 11.10 automatically unmutes when I play a Youtube video.  It might be a general flash problem.  How do I configure the sound to never be modified by programs unless I control it do to so?

Comment: Where are you muting it? In YouTube or from the Ubuntu panel?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards

Comment: I have experienced this as well in 12.04!  I have the system audio muted (as displayed in the small bar by the clock) and when loading a page with a video/ad in it that plays automatically, the sound it unmuted!  Very uncool.

Comment: I have the same problem with ubuntu 16.04.